# Bitnami Django Server (AWS) /libcrypto.so.1.0.0 error

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, bitnami

I'm attempting to run django on AWS using Bitnami's Django Server. I'm getting an error when I run the restart command that blocks me from connection over Filezilla. (I can still get in via SSH)  It's telling me that I'm missing libcrytpo.so.1.0.0 library.

Here's my input:

sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start

And the output:

```
server started
/opt/bitnami/postgresql/scripts/ctl.sh : postgresql  started at port 5432
Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started at port 80
monit: /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by monit)
monit: /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by monit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here,

The monit issue is an issue that we fixed in the past and I just launched a Bitnami Django stack 1.8.11 and it works properly, but you can manually fix the libraries related issues by running the commands below that will do the required substitutions in the /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh script

```
sudo cp /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh.bck
sudo sed -i 's/monit unmonitor all/env -i monit unmonitor all/g' /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh
sudo sed -i 's/monit monitor all/env -i monit monitor all/g' /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh
sudo sed -i 's/monit monitor $2/env -i monit monitor $2/g' /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh
sudo sed -i 's/monit unmonitor $2/env -i monit unmonitor $2/g' /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh
```

You could recover the previous ctlscript.sh file easily if something went wrong

```
sudo cp /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh.bck /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh
```

Let us know if it works for you.

Regards,

Jota